# Code not working after little change

Tags: ruby

I'm beginner in programming, I changed my code a little bit so that I can execute some def from the command line. After that change I got an error, but first my code:

```
require 'faraday'

@conn = Faraday.new 'https://zombost.de:8673/rest', :ssl => {:verify => false}
@uid = '8978'

def certificate
  res = conn.get do |request|
    request.url "acc/#{@uid}/cere"
  end
end

def suchen(input)
  @suche = input
  @res = @conn.get do |request|  
    request.url "acc/?search=#{@suche}"
  end
end

puts @res.body
```

Then I wrote into the console:

```
ruby prog.rb suchen(jumbo)
```

So, somehow i get the error:

```
Undefined method body for Nilclass
```

Comment: Why do you downvote it? Im beginner

Comment: Among other things, your shell syntax is invalid.

Comment: Isnt it possible to call the def suchen from the console?

Comment: @JohnSmith No, it's not. You can call it from within an irb console, but you cannot pass it as an argument to `ruby`. Everything after your program name is simply passed to the script as a string argument, made available via the `ARGV` array.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not invoking either of your methods, so `@res` is never assigned to.

`@res` evaluates to `nil`, so you're invoking `nil.body`.

---

RE: Your update:

> ruby prog.rb suchen(jumbo)

That isn't how you invoke a method. You have to call it from *within the source file*. All you're doing is passing an argument to your script, which will be a simple string available in the `ARGV` array.

---

RE: Your comment:

It should go without saying that the solution is to *actually invoke your method*.

Comment: So whats the solution? H

Comment: Is it possible to invoke a method from the console

Answer (score 0):

You can call the methods from the command line. Ruby has a function `eval` which evaluates a string. You can eval the command line argument strings.

Here's how. Change the line `puts @res.body` to

```
str = ARGV[1]
eval(ARGV[0])
puts @res.body
```

then run your program like so

```
$ ruby prog.rb suchen\(str\) jumbo
```